# wlan0 No such device

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, lan

I am trying to run these two commands in an attempt to fix my intermittent wireless connection

```
iwconfig wlan0
sudo iwconfig wlan0 power off
```

But I get this error

```
wlan0     No such device
```

Comment: Please edit to add results for `lsusb; lspci -nnk | grep -iA3 net; iwconfig`

Comment: @Jeremy31 updated per your recommendation

Comment: sounds like you're using the wrong name for the network device use **ifconfig** to see what your network device name is(it will be on the left hand side along with lo)

Comment: updated per your recommendation. Does that change anything?

Comment: whatever name you get on the left top of the command ifconfig is your network device name and should be used instead of wlan0 (wlp4s0 in your case)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to your question is to use `sudo iwconfig wlp4s0 power off`
But I doubt if it will fix your issue as the ath9k module blocks power management changes unless you

```
sudo modprobe -r ath9k
sudo modprobe -r ath9k ps_enable=1
```

You may actually want to try

```
sudo sed -i 's/wifi.powersave = 3/wifi.powersave = 2/' /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf
systemctl restart network-manager.service
```

Comment: The issue with using wlan0 is that it doesn't exist, your wifi interface is wlp4s0.  The ps_enable will switch back to default on a reboot and the sudo sed command can be reversed by changing where the 2 and 3 are

Answer (score 1):

Your wlan0 name adapter is wlp4s0.

Correct use of wlp4s0:

```
iwconfig wlp4s0
sudo iwconfig wlp4s0 power off
```

Answer (score 0):

try adding the network you are trying to connect manually. it worked for me I'm running kali Linux as a main OS with xfce.

Comment: ...though of course Kali isn't Ubuntu!

Comment: but both are on Debian